# How to find master GIT URL

Tags: git, teamcity

I have pushed project into GIT - stash and its URL is appearing for clone is as below:

https://username%40ff.com@stash.intranet.ff.com:5716/scm/projectname.git

Now, I need to user GIT repository URL into team city to build and generate artifacts.

so, it should be master GIT repository URL.
But, I could not find master GIT repository URL to link up.

when I executed - `git branch -r` then, getting message as `origin/master` but I need URL as shown above.

Can any one please share me how to find master GIT stash URL so, I could link it into team city VCS configuration.

thanks
Dhaval

Comment: Did you try to look into your `.git/config` file?

Comment: ok, it shows same URL with my username. (same as clone URL).Is there reason like I had pushed first master copy and due to that master fetch URL is containing my username. or something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the URL you have without the username in it, i.e.

```
https://stash.intranet.ff.com:5716/scm/projectname.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey just try out following command to get master branch url:

git remote show origin

It will result like this:
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/demo/myfile.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/demo/myfile.git
  HEAD branch: master

Comment: Its result as you mentioned above. But, giving URL with my user name. Is there reason like I had pushed first master copy and due to that  master fetch URL is containing my username. or something wrong ?